# How to count distinct fields and calling it in the where statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

I am trying to count the number of duplicates that appears on a table for example:

```
First| Last  | ADDR1           | City      | ST | Zip
-----+-------+-----------------+-----------+----+------
John | Smith | 1234 Fake St.   | Hollywood | CA | 12345
John | Smith | 1234 Fake St.   | Hollywood | CA | 12345
John | Smith | 1234 Fake St.   | Hollywood | CA | 12345
John | Smith | 1234 Fake St.   | Hollywood | CA | 12345
Jane | Smith | 1111 Junkertown | Phoenix   | AR | 22222
Jane | Smith | 1111 Junkertown | Phoenix   | AR | 22222
Jane | Smith | 1111 Junkertown | Phoenix   | AR | 22222
```

Here is my select statement however it is not liking my where statement. I only want to return rows with counts > 1

```
select distinct t.first_name, t.last_name, t.addr_line_1, t.city, 
                t.state_cd, t.zip, count(*) as numberofdupes
from name_addr t
where numberofdupes > 1
group by t.first_name, t.last_name, t.addr_line_1, t.city, t.state_cd, t.zip
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction. Please and thank you.

Comment: Skip the WHERE clause, instead add `having count(*) > 1` at the end.

Comment: No need to SELECT DISTINCT, the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skip the `WHERE` clause, use `HAVING` for aggregate function conditions.

No need to do `SELECT DISTINCT`, the `GROUP BY` returns no duplicate rows.

```
select t.first_name, t.last_name, t.addr_line_1, t.city, 
       t.state_cd, t.zip, count(*) as numberofdupes
from name_addr t
group by t.first_name, t.last_name, t.addr_line_1, t.city, t.state_cd, t.zip
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter by the results of the grouping, then you need to put your filters in the `HAVING` (after the `GROUP BY`) instead of the `WHERE`.

```
select t.first_name, t.last_name, t.addr_line_1, t.city, 
                t.state_cd, t.zip, count(*) as numberofdupes
from name_addr t
group by t.first_name, t.last_name, t.addr_line_1, t.city, t.state_cd, t.zip
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

You can also remove the `DISTINCT` if you are already grouping by all the columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct t.first_name, t.last_name, t.addr_line_1, t.city, 
       t.state_cd, t.zip, count(*) as numberofdupes
from name_addr t
group by t.first_name, t.last_name, t.addr_line_1, t.city, t.state_cd, t.zip
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```